# working with Microsoft.Lync from c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, lync

i want to work with microsoft Lync through winodws application written in c#.
I have installed, visual studio 2010, micorosoft Lync 2013, microsoft Lync 2010 SDK.

but when i want to make reference to microsoft inside the visual studio there is no 
"Microsoft.Lync.Model"   or "Microsoft.Lync.Utilities" or "Microsoft.Lync.Controls" or any thing related to Microsoft.Lync

how can I make a reference to Microsoft.Lync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the dlls according to the sdk installation path

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933180(v=office.15).aspx (lync 2013)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh378534(v=office.14).aspx (lync 2010)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different SDKs and APIs available for Lync development - take a look at the link below for a great summary, as well as links to libraries of sample code and applications.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/gg455051%28v=office.14%29

There are a number of examples that demonstrate how to reference the various DLL's.

You also mention you're using the Lync 2010 SDK with Lync 2013 - check out the Lync 2013 SDK as it is more appropriate for the platform you're using.